# scenebuilder 8.4.1: custom font property not visible on custom properties section

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

create a custom component, make it a jar and add it to the scenebuilder libraries so that it is visible => OK
declare string / float / integer / object properties  etc so that they are visible in scenebuilder => Ok

But I can not declare a property "Font" and be visible in the custom properties of scenebuilder.

I do this in my controller class:

```
private SimpleObjectProperty<Font> TextFont = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Font.font("System",FontWeight.NORMAL,12));

public Font getTextFont() {
    return TextFont.get();
}

public SimpleObjectProperty<Font> textFontProperty() {
    return TextFont;
}

public void setTextFont(Font textFont) {
    this.TextFont.set(textFont);
       }
```

my other properties appear but not this one.

if anyone has any documentation on it...

thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Actually, there is a bug on Scene Builder, as the `Font` type wasn't inspected for custom controls. I've filed it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/175/font-editor-not-added-to-inspector-for).

Comment: Ok thanks, so i've to wait for a new release of scenebuilder that include your solution... i 'll do without waiting for it